# Stripe cashier 13.0 laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I would like help because I still can't find a solution on the new cashier version v13 $ payment method = $ request-> payment method; returns an empty payment method, entering a specific card pm_card_visa works, but the default payment method doesn't work, what could be? Thank you in advance

```
   public function create(Request $request, Plan $plan)
{
    $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->get('plan'));

    $user = $request->user();

    $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
    $payment_method = $request->payment_method;
    if(!$user->hasPaymentMethod()){
        $user->addPaymentMethod($payment_method);
        $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($payment_method);
    }
    else{
        foreach ($user->paymentMethods() as $payment){
            if($payment->asStripePaymentMethod()->id == $payment_method){
                $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($payment_method);
            }
        }
    }

    $user->newSubscription('default', $plan->stripe_plan)
        ->create($payment_method, [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ]);

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
}
```

Comment: If you can't get the paymentMethod from XHR follow the instruction from stripe js api to set the component to request the credit card, in any case in test mode you only can use test cards. https://stripe.com/docs/js/including

Comment: What could be wrong with my javascript code that doesn't get the card data?
code here:  https://pastebin.com/YeqpVa0j